# Tesseract - getting alternative results with confidence level

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use tesseract to recognize numbers. It works pretty well but sometimes I get wrong results (8 instead of 9 etc). I know how to improve accuracy with some non-ocr methods but I need other results with confidence levels. I found out that I get the best choices using a ChoiceIterator for each ResultIterator:

```
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;    
    tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);    
    tess.SetVariable("save_best_choices", "T");

    [setting input image here] 

    tess.Recognize(NULL);
    tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = tess.GetIterator();
    tesseract::ChoiceIterator* ci; 
    if(ri != 0)
    {
        char* symbol = ri->GetUTF8Text(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL);

        if(symbol != 0)
        {
            float conf = ri->Confidence(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL); 
            cout << symbol << "\tconf: " << conf << "\n"; 

            const tesseract::ResultIterator itr = *ri; 
            ci = new tesseract::ChoiceIterator(itr);
            do {
                const char* choice = ci->GetUTF8Text(); 
                if (choice) {
                    std::cout << "\t" << choice << " conf: " << ci->Confidence() << "\n"; 
                }
            } while(ci->Next());                

            //  delete[] symbol;
        }           
    }
```

But the problem is that ci->GetUTF8Text() always returns a null pointer.

I'm using tesseract 3.02 as DLL, compiled under MSVC2010 express.

Answer (score 0):

From limited research earlier today, I think the answer might be setting the variable `SaveBlobChoices` versus `SaveBestChoices`. I still need to test this myself.